# Building HTML from Javascript in Asp

Tags: javascript, asp.net

What is wrong with this formated string?

```
function buildDialog()
    {
        var str = '<owd:Dialog id="a_myDialog" Title="my Dialog" Width="400" Height="215" StyleFolder ="wdstyles/default"' +
        'IsModal="true" runat="server">' + '... Hello world ...' + ' <br /> ' +
                   '<asp:button id="aspButton1" text="Yes" runat="server" onclick="btnAlert_Click" />' +
                    '<input type="button"  id="client_no_commit" value="No" onclick="a_myDialog.Close()"/>' +
                '</owd:Dialog>';

        alert($(str));

    }
```

I'm trying to create the above dialog but Visual Studio 2015 keeps saying there is an error on the first line? jQuery is optional.

Comment: Looks totally correct to me.

Comment: It is supposed to generate the dialog but the parsing stops on the first line.

Comment: @user2415266 It is not correct in ASP.NET, you cannot create server side controls from client side markup like that. You may want to be careful answering ASP.NET questions like this in the future to avoid confusion. ASP.NET does processing *on the server* of special markup to generate resulting HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't using *client side* code to generate server side code. By the time the browser has generated the ASP, the server will have finished running the ASP and sent the result to the browser.

The error report probably has to do with you attempting to use ASP tags inside a script element.

Comment: Probably, but you have to deal with the DOM you have in the browser, not the ASP that generated the HTML that generated the DOM.

Comment: I've tried to access the html from javascript with: document.getElementById('a_myDialog').InnerHTML = str; but the element is null. I've also tried window.onload with the same result.

Comment: Have you looked at the DOM with a DOM inspector? I was under the impression that the `id` attribute in ASP was a server side ID, not a client side ID.

Comment: @Quentin You are correct, that is the default behavior that manifest itself in templated control or master page situations etc. You can get around it by adding a `ClientIdMode="static"` attribute to the element (you can also set this at the page or application levels), or you can use special syntax to embed the correct ID, such as `var element = '<%= a_myDialog.ClientId %>';`. Or you can use classes, but I dislike that when referring to a specific element.